# Probability axiom

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, conditional-probability

Given that

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$$

would it also thus be accurate to say that

$$P(A \cup B^C) = P(A) + P(B^C) - P(A\cap B^C)$$

Comment: Absolutely.  Just rename $B$ to $B^C$

Comment: where $B^C$ would represent the complement of B, so like $P(B^C) = 1 - P(B)$?

Comment: Inclusion exclusion says that the probability of the union of two events is equal to the sum of the probabilities of the events individually minus the probability of the intersection of the events.  This is true regardless what events they happened to be or what they are named, regardless how complicated or simple the events were written.  It works whether in place of $B$ we had $B^c$, it works whether in place of $B$ we had $((C\cap O)\cup (M\cap P\cap L))\setminus (E\cup X)$ or anything else.  All that we required was that they were both events.

Comment: Also, as an aside, Inclusion-exclusion is generally not taken as an axiom by itself but is rather proven from other axioms.